# Websocket onMessage required but value undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket

I'm wondering why this is happening?

Failed prop type: The prop `onMessage` is marked as required in `Websocket`, but its value is `undefined`.
    in Websocket (created by LobbyBase)

This is my lobby base

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Websocket from 'react-websocket'
import $ from 'jquery'

class LobbyBase extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            player_game_list: [],
            available_game_list: []
        }

        // bind button click
        //this.sendSocketMessage = this.sendSocketMessage.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {

    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.serverRequest.abort();
    }

    handleData(data) {
        //receives messages from the connected websocket
        let result = JSON.parse(data)


        // we've received an updated list of available games
        this.setState({available_game_list: result})
    }

    sendSocketMessage(message){
        // sends message to channels back-end
       const socket = this.refs.socket
       socket.state.ws.send(JSON.stringify(message))
    }

    render() {
        return (

            <div className="row">
                <Websocket url={this.props.socket}
                    onMessage={this.handleData.bind(this)}
                    />
                <span>Lobby Components will go here....</span>
            </div>

        )
    }
}

LobbyBase.propTypes = {
    socket: PropTypes.string
};

export default LobbyBase;
```

And this is my url (which is in index)

```
var lobby_sock = 'ws://' + window.location.host + "/ws/lobby/"
```

I've seen people do similar code for declaration of websocket. Any help will be appreciated!

EDIT: more information on handle data

```
 handleData(data) {
        //receives messages from the connected websocket
        let result = JSON.parse(data)


        // we've received an updated list of available games
        this.setState({available_game_list: result})
    }
```

Comment: Rather than pass in a new function into `Websocket` on render each time using `bind`, you should use `handleData = (data) => { ... }`, which has the same behavior as attaching the function directly to the instance in the `constructor`. Then you just have to pass `onMessage={this.handleData}`, and the function reference will always be the same.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the suggestion. I do have a handleData though. Should I simply delete the .bind(this) part? I'm really new to javascript and websocket in general. Thanks a lot!